# Typescript check whether a type is exact union of other union type

Tags: typescript

```
type A = string | {a:1}

type B = ExactUnion<A, A> // true
type C = ExactUnion<string, A > // false
type D = ExactUnion<{a:1},A> // false
```

I need a utility type to determine whether Union A  = Union B exactly, just like look into a mirror

this is what I tried

```
type ExactUnion<A,B> = A extends B? B extends A ? true : false : false
```

obviously it doesn't work, it returns `boolean` for every case

is it possible? if so how?

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=3&ssc=71&pln=3&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDOwBOBLAdgcygHygG8BDALgEYBfAKGtEigFEAPYgY2AFVN0B7TADwwANACEAfAlhQIzYBEwATJFFEB%20VTLkLl0jWgCu0UlABmxADZJjZy9dr1ooqS3Zce-IcNiSA9L6hDCDpwaABhF1YObj5BFAwcbzg-APMrYMcoABEEV2iPQRIKSmEYFNt0oA)

Comment: Like [this](https://tsplay.dev/w16OAN) maybe?  Your conditional types seem to be unintentionally [distributive](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) which is not what you want.  But I don't understand the "exact union" terminology.  This is really more like "mutually extends", since `ExactUnion<3, 3>` will be `true` (and neither is a union) and `ExactUnion<{a?: 1}, {}>` will also be `true` (and while they are not identical types they are considered to mutually extend each other).  Can you [edit] to be more clear?

Comment: i think the best word to use is 'mirror', the types in the union A must be exactly same as types in the union B, just like looking into a mirror